# Loading sound before game starts in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

I used following logic to load the sound from a different thread to load it while my game goes on.
Though it works for very small wav files, sometimes, I have to wait till it loads.

How can I make sure that it is loaded beforehand?

```
   public class MusicPlayer implements Runnable {

    String sound;
    Player p;

    public MusicPlayer(String sound)
    {
        this.sound = sound;

        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+sound);
        try
        {
            p = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/X-wav");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}

    }

    public void start()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            p.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody needs it, The best way I found is actually initialize the object in Main thread itself. If not the fastest, it will be the most reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most reliable solution is to create a progress bar and wait for the sounds to get loaded, so this will keep the user entertained a little as he can see something moving

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Comment: Even if that works, it will ruin my thread. I think I should do some preloading in the main thread only. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I meant it will ruin my game which needs foremost attention.

Answer (score -1):

You could add a delay I.E  Thread.sleep(100);  this will delay the thread for 100 milliseconds

Comment: lol ... I want my content to load faster. Not to delay the load.